# C# Convert Action<int> to lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following code:

```
int[] iArray = new int[] { 2, 3, 4 };
Action<int> action = new Action<int>(ShowSquares);
Array.ForEach(iArray, action);

private static void ShowSquares(int val)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0:d} squared = {1:d}", val, val * val);
}
```

While this code works, I want to convert the second line

```
Action<int> action = new Action<int>(ShowSquares);
```

to use a lambda expression.

Is this possible?

TIA

Comment: To see if it could be done.  I'm trying to gain a deeper insight to lambda expressions.

Answer (score 3):

```
int[] iArray = new int[] { 2, 3, 4 };
Array.ForEach(iArray, val => Console.WriteLine("{0:d} squared = {1:d}", val, val * val));
```

The lambda generated will be the same as your `ShowSquares` method.  As long as you don't need to use `action` later, you can declare it inline in the `ForEach` method instead of declaring the action first.  Also, as an exercise to learn about delegates and lambdas this is good, but in practice, I'd suggest:

```
int[] iArray = new int[] { 2, 3, 4 };
foreach (var val in iArray)
    Console.WriteLine("{0:d} squared = {1:d}", val, val * val));
```

Or, if the final line would be reused elsewhere, break it back out into a `ShowSquares` method.

Answer (score 3):

```
Action<int> action = (a) => ShowSquares(a);
```

Comment: Why are the parenthesis needed around the (a)?  This must be a personal preference.  I did it with and without the parenthesis and LinqPad 4 doesn't seem to mind.

Comment: You're right, they're optional (simply personal preference).  I prefer not to have them, as it makes the code shorter.  You might prefer them because it looks more like an ordinary method declaration.

Comment: I wouldn't use parentheses when passing a lambda like this to a function, but in an assignment situation, the `= a =>` tokens just look weird/wrong to me, and so I feel like adding the ( ) make the code clearer.

Comment: Good point about it looking weird/wrong.  Tim S. also has a good point about not having them.

Answer (score 3):

```
Array.ForEach(iArray, i=>ShowSquares(i));
```

Comment: I like this approach.  Too bad I couldn't have thought of this.